# Generate a rtl version of css with extract text webpack plugin

Tags: sass, webpack, arabic, right-to-left

I would like to extract two versions of the CSS file, one that supports RTL and one that supports LTR.

I would have a server flag that determines which file to include. Is there a webpack loader that can help me do that and works well with extract text webpack plugin?

Comment: There is a simple solution: add second config for RTL and generate css twice.

Comment: I've made a webpack plugin for that, that works in addition to the extract text plugin: https://github.com/romainberger/webpack-rtl-plugin
Hope this helps and solves your issue.